# Is there a method for deleting only 1 matching array element?

Tags: ruby, arrays

e.g. `a = [1,2,3,1]`

If you use `a.delete 1` the result is `a = [2,3]`

Is there a method where you can delete from the array with a limit? Pseudo code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,1]
a.delete(1, *limit 1*) 
#=> [2,3,4,1]
```

Comment: what is first `1` for ?

Comment: first 1 is the value to delete

Comment: `limit` is saying what ?

Comment: only delete 1 of this from this array

Comment: `1` from anywhere? or the first `1` ?

Comment: anywhere just dont delete more than one `1` and it can be anywhere in the array.. maybe middle, maybe second, first, maybe last element

Comment: Yes...got your point. These all information, you should give us on the first place. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete only one:

```
if idx = a.index(n)
  a.delete_at(idx)
end
```

for a generic `limit > 0`

```
def delete_first(arr, item, limit = 1)
  arr.reject! { |i| i == item && (limit -= 1) >= 0 } 
end
```

with additional optimization (does not pass through all the array if already dropped all relevant elements):

```
def delete_first(arr, item, limit = 1)
  arr.reject! { |i| return arr if limit == 0; i == item && limit -= 1 }
end
```

Comment: The optimized solution is a clear winner. Thanks Uri.

Answer (score 7):

I can think of one idea for this is -

```
n.times { array.delete_at array.index(item) }
```

[`delete_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) - *Deletes the element at the specified index, returning that element, or nil if the index is out of range.*

[`index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-index) - *Returns the index of the first object in ary such that the object is == to obj.*

You can wrap the logic inside a method as below :-

```
def delete_with_limit(array, item, limit)
  count = array.count(item)
  raise "only #{count} is present, and you are expecting #{limit}" if limit > count
  limit.times { array.delete_at array.index(item) }
  array
end

array = [1,2,1,1,3,5]
delete_with_limit(array, 1, 2) # => [2, 1, 3, 5]
array = [1,2,1,1,3,5]
delete_with_limit(array, 1, 4)
#  `delete_with_limit': only 3 is present, and you are expecting 4 (RuntimeError)
```

Answer (score 1):

A working solution:

```
n = 1
a = [1,2,3,4,1]
a.delete_at(a.index(n) || a.length)

#=> [2,3,4,1]
```

Comment: Try it out.. it deletes the first matching element only.

Comment: what if, I want to delete any 3 ?

Comment: Thats a different question :)

Comment: @go____yourself It is not a different question. In the question, you wrote "delete from the array with a limit", instead of "delete from the array once". That surely implies that the number of times to delete is not restricted to once.

Comment: At @sawa but the question says only 1 matching array element, hence the limit being 1. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.  My thanks to @Uri for the suggested improvement.  (See the edit history if you are interested in what I had initially.)

**Method**

```
def delete_some(arr, target, nbr_to_delete)
  arr.select { |e| e==target ?
                (nbr_to_delete > 0 ? (nbr_to_delete -= 1; false) : true) :
                true }
end
```

**Examples**

```
a = [1,2,3,1,2,1,1,3]

delete_some(a,1,0) #=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
delete_some(a,1,1) #=> [2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
delete_some(a,1,2) #=> [2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3]
delete_some(a,1,3) #=> [2, 3, 2, 1, 3]
delete_some(a,1,4) #=> [2, 3, 2, 3]
delete_some(a,1,5) #=> [2, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `select`?

Comment: how about `arr.reject { |e| e==target && (nbr_to_delete -= 1) >= 0 }`?

Comment: Good approach for not taking help of `raise`... :-)

Comment: Yes, that's better yet, @Uri.